# Copiar a portapapeles con retardo

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Uso este código para copiar el portapapeles:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function copiarAlPortapapeles("p1") {         
      var aux = document.createElement("input");
      aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML);
      document.body.appendChild(aux);
      aux.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      document.body.removeChild(aux);
    }

</script>
```

Para ejecutarlo uso: `onclick="copiarAlPortapapeles()"`

El código funciona pero tengo un problema, esta función está en un `submit`, que muestra por ajax un resultado.

Lo que sucede es que se ejecuta antes la copia al portapapeles que aparece la función ajax (en php) por lo que copia lo anterior.

He pensado en retrasar el código tal que así: `onclick="setTimeout ('copiarAlPortapapeles();', 2000);"`

Pero no me funciona... ¿alguna ayuda?

el codigo ajax:

```
<script language="javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Esta primera parte crea un loader no es necesaria
    $().ajaxStart(function() {
        $('#loading').show();
        $('#result').hide();
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#result').fadeIn('slow');
    });
   // Interceptamos el evento submit
    $('#form, #fat, #signup-forma').submit(function() {

  // Enviamos el formulario usando AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            // Mostramos un mensaje con la respuesta de PHP
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);

            }
        })        
        return false;
    }); 
})
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Si estás haciendo llamadas AJAX tendrás un `callback`, ¿porqué no ejecutas tu método en el `callback` de tu AJAX?

Comment: Deberías tener un `OnSuccess` o algun `calback`. Pon ahí el código de copia al portapapeles y ya está! Edit: OOps @eledgaar se ha adelantado.

Comment: Deberíais poner eso como respuesta y no como comentario

Comment: el código para copiar ya esta en el calback, pero lo que tiene que hacer que se ejecute esta fuera de el. el problema es que copia antes de que aparezca lo que tiene que salir, entonces copia en blanco.

Comment: @EnriqueBallesterGómez Se refieren al _callback_ de la llamada AJAX. Tal y como está ahora mismo, estás llamando a la función cuando se pulse el botón, sin asociarlo de ninguna manera con la llamada AJAX que parece ir por su cuenta

Comment: e añadido el ajax que uso.

Comment: dudo mucho que `copiarAlPortapales` compile asi como esta, elimina la parte de "P1" en la definicion. deberia decir `Unexpected string` en el log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Llámalo desde la función `success` de la llamada `$.ajax()`

```
...  
success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
    copiarAlPortapapeles();
}
...
```

Comment: no funciona, no lo copia. :(

Comment: @EnriqueBallesterGómez dudo mucho que copiarAlPortapales compile asi como esta definida, elimina la parte de "P1" en la definicion. Tal y como esta seguramente dice `Unexpected string` en el log.